# Error importing skimage import data, filters

Tags: python, image-processing, libraries

I am new to image processing in python. I intended to import `from skimage import data, filter` in python(version 19.3) but I encountered this error

> `Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/John_Bardeen/IdeaProjects/untitled5/.idea/pythonApp.py", line 6, in <module>
>       from skimage import data, filter
>     File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\skimage\__init__.py", line 127, in <module>
>       from .util.dtype import (img_as_float32,
>     File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\skimage\util\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
>       from ._montage import montage
>     File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\skimage\util\_montage.py", line 2, in <module>
>       from .. import exposure
>     File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\skimage\exposure\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
>       from .exposure import histogram, equalize_hist, \
>     File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\skimage\exposure\exposure.py", line 3, in <module>
>       from ..color import rgb2gray
>     File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\skimage\color\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
>       from .colorconv import (convert_colorspace,
>     File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\skimage\color\colorconv.py", line 55, in <module>
>       from scipy import linalg
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'`

can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you need to install `scipy` using below code.

```
pip install scipy
```